# Can't transfer seahorse keyrings [16.04]

Tags: password, keyrings, gnome-keyring, seahorse

I'm using 16.04 and can't transfer my keyring files to another computer with 16.04. Seahorse versions are the same: 3.18.0 Permissions are right.

Say, I have default keyring which is usually named login. Then, I can edit it on new computer adding info from my old login keyring (ommiting old header, of course). And after I restart seahorse keyring dissapears from it's interface. But! If I edit it again and remove all the info leaving only original header it re-appears again. Which is looks like there is must be checksum somewhere or something else.

Is there something I can do to transfer my keyrings?

Comment: Have you tried doing it while the user is NOT logged in on the second computer?

Comment: I'll try, but it looks like nothing to do with it. It looks like there is checksum somewhere

Comment: The user must be logged out without the keyring service running., in order to overwrite the files. Seahorse does not read the keyring files itself. It simply talks to the keyring service.

Comment: @dobey Thanks! I did not know about keyring service. It appears you can just kill it, copy files over and restart it again. Add you suggestion as an answer and I will mark it as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To overwrite the keyring files on disk, the keyring service must not be running.

The easiest and best way to accomplish this is to simply log out from the graphical session, copy the files via ssh or via console login, and then you can log into the graphical session and keyring will have the data you were expecting.